# DateDiff Count Number of occurrences of each month, weekly between dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have some resourcing data based on estimations showing me hours per month for each "role" assigned to a task.

I need to be able to count the number of times a "month" appears in a weekly count between two dates. So i can split the hours accordingly.

i.e between 02-Oct-21 and 27-Nov-21 there is 9 weeks, output from the below code:

```
Public Sub dtConv()

Dim stDt, enDt As Date

stDt = Sheets("New Job Template").Range("F1").Value
enDt = Sheets("New Job Template").Range("H1").Value

Debug.Print (DateDiff("ww", stDt, enDt))

End Sub
```

Shows me 8 weeks (this is wrong).

But the above does not tell me that "November" occurs 5 times, "December" occurs 4 times.

Can I leverage DateDiff to also count the number of times Nov/Dec/Jan etc occurs between start/end dates?

Comment: Can you show your data?  I don't know about anyone else but I find it hard to understand exactly what you're wanting to do.

Comment: @Skin data is irrelevant here. Two Dates. A and B. Count number of weeks between A and B (above code). Also count number of times each  month within A and B  shows up.

Comment: Ok, I get it now.  I can't see anyway to do this other than a loop.

Comment: What's considered to be the first day of the week?  Monday?  Sunday?  You need to be able to break out the weeks in an array (or something) so you can then work out the ranges to work within.

Comment: Sunday-Saturday. DateDiff counts the correct number of weeks between these two dates i provided so it shouldnt matter much?

Comment: I assume the dates may be split over non-perfect weeks?  i.e. the first date could start on a Wednesday and the end date be on a Friday?!?

Comment: I think it matters because you want to count how many times a month appears in a given range of weeks.  At the day level, for your example, the month of November appears 27 times.  To determine it at the week level, you need to know when the weeks start and ends.  If I'm wrong, then I've misunderstood what you want to achieve.  If your ranges are 15/10 - 22/10 ... 23/10 - 30/10 ... 31/10 - 6/11 ... 7/11 - 14/11 ... 15/11 - 21/11 ... then I would've calculated that October occurs 3 times and November 4 times.  Is that what you want?

Comment: There is 9 weeks between and including the two date values provided (02-Oct-21 - 27-Nov-21).
So the above formula in my Q is actually wrong (it spits out 8).

The dates values (the saturday of the week) between these values are 09-Oct-21, 16-Oct-21, 23-Oct-21, 30-Oct-21,06-Nov-21,13-Nov-21,20-Nov-21.

So theres 9 Weeks in this range, further to that, October Appears 5 Times, Nov Appears 4 times.

Comment: @Krono, just an observation. `stDt` is declared as a variant, not a date. You need ` as Date` to follow each variable declaration, not just at the end of the line.

Comment: So, you need the number of (different) weeks in between, **even if not full**, and how many times the two involved months (October and November) appear in the date range. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes that is correct. Though the start/end dates will span many months, not just two.

Comment: I was talking about the question as you formulated it... My answer accepts any date interval, no matter how many months involved. But, in order to make it return each month number of occurrences I created two specific variables. I can adapt the code to 'detect' the involved months and return the occurrences number for each of them, if this is the need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It will return the correct number of weeks, October and November months occurrences:

```
Private Sub testTextEvaluateDateManyMonths()
 Dim arrD, stDt As Date, enDt As Date, noD As Long, startD As Long, startM As Long, i As Long, mName As String
 Dim WCount As Long, prevWNo As Long, wNo As Long, k As Long, dictM As Object
 Const firstWeekDay As Long = vbMonday '(2) you should use here your first day of the week.
                                                        ' for Sunday you should use vbSunday, or 1

  stDt = "02-Oct-21": enDt = "28-Feb-22"
  noD = enDt - stDt + 1      ' number of involved days between the two date
  startM = month(stDt)       ' month number in stDt
  startD = Day(stDt)         ' day number in stDt
  'create an array of involved dates:
  'arrD = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("TEXT(DATE(2021," & startM & ",row(" & startD & ":" & noD + 1 & ")),""dd.mm.yyyy"")"))
  arrD = Evaluate("TEXT(DATE(2021," & startM & ",row(" & startD & ":" & noD + 1 & ")),""dd.mm.yyyy"")")
  ReDim arrMonths(DateDiff("m", stDt, enDt, vbMonday))
  Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(arrD), "|") 'just to see the date range in Immediate Window...
  Set dictM = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrD)
    wNo = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(CDate(arrD(i, 1)), firstWeekDay)
    If wNo <> prevWNo Then prevWNo = wNo: WCount = WCount + 1
    mName = Format(CDate(arrD(i, 1)), "mmmm")
    dictM(mName) = dictM(mName) + 1
  Next i

  For i = 0 To dictM.Count - 1
        Debug.Print "Month " & dictM.Keys()(i) & " appears " & dictM.items()(i) & " times."
  Next i
  Debug.Print "Weeks number: " & WCount
End Sub
```

The above code builds an array of the necessary days range and analyze it very fast (in memory), extracting what (I understood) you need.

`firstWeekDay` constant is needed. If "02-Oct-21" would be Sunday on Monday the function to return week number may return a week (ending in Sunday) in plus or in minus. For the range you need (now) it doesn't matter, but if you change the involved date, **it may matter**, for an accurate return...

If something not clear or other things to be extracted from the days range, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: @Krono Adapted the code to deliver all number of involved months, independent of their number. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want but see how you go and adapt it as need be.  Could it be done better?!?  Maybe!

Add a reference to `Scripting.Dictionary` in your project and put your dates in `A1` (From date) and `A2` (To date) respectively.

```
Public Sub CountMonthsInWeeks()
    Dim objValues As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim dtFrom As Date, dtTo As Date, bDone As Boolean
    Dim dtFromTemp As Date, dtToTemp As Date, intMonth As Integer
    Dim strKey As Variant, strMonth As String
    
    Set objValues = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    dtFrom = CDate(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value)
    dtTo = CDate(Sheet1.Range("A2").Value) - 1
    
    dtFromTemp = dtFrom
    
    Do While Not bDone
        dtToTemp = dtFromTemp + 6
        
        Debug.Print "From = " & dtFromTemp & ", To = " & dtToTemp
        
        If dtToTemp >= dtTo Then
            dtToTemp = dtTo
            bDone = True
        End If
        
        UpdateMonthCount objValues, Month(dtFromTemp)
        If Month(dtToTemp) <> Month(dtFromTemp) Then UpdateMonthCount objValues, Month(dtToTemp)
        
        dtFromTemp = dtToTemp + 1
    Loop
    
    Debug.Print ""
    
    For Each strKey In objValues.Keys
        strMonth = WorksheetFunction.Text(DateSerial(Year(Now), strKey, 1), "mmm")
        Debug.Print "Month " & strMonth & " = " & objValues.Item(strKey)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateMonthCount(ByRef objValues As Scripting.Dictionary, ByVal intMonth As Integer)
    If Not objValues.Exists(intMonth) Then objValues.Add intMonth, 0
    objValues.Item(intMonth) = objValues.Item(intMonth) + 1
End Sub
```

I've made an assumption that the start date will always be the correct day, I'm not checking to see if it's as you described.  It seems like overkill to me.